# Make floating divs appears one by one with Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code of a [tutorial](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery) to animate divs,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
        offset: 100
       });
});
```

I have floating divs, **how can I make it animates one by one not row by row ?**

what I've tried to use the below code with the previous one but I don't know how can make it works

```
.each(function(index){
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout( function(){ $(_this).fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000*index );
});
```

**Here you are My Html**

```
<div class="post">
    <span class="icon fa fa-camera-retro"> </span>
    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
    <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, .</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <span class="icon fa fa-camera-retro"> </span>
    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
    <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, .</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <span class="icon fa fa-camera-retro"> </span>
    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
    <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, .</p>
</div>
```

**Css code**

```
.post{
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
        height:420px;
        width:440px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

Comment: instead of .col , use .post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('.post').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).show(3000);
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pqPeitx3yhHM8ktS3ysa

Comment: thank you, what I need is to use similar to this code within the JQuery code which at the top of this page

Comment: If im right pls write this code inside self invoking function

Comment: $(function(){
  $('.post').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).show(3000);
  });
});

Comment: sorry How can I use it within my code `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({` .......

Comment: Try this usama jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.post').each(function(i,e){
    jQuery(this).show(3000);
  });
});